# Ratio between starting wage and requested raise

Tags: salary, negotiation, raise

I brought a brand new business to my current company (SW development where only mechanic and analog HW products were produced). This meant also building up (under my guide) all the needed infrustructure and processes to accomplish the new activities (tools, rules, equipment, etc.), which are usually already in place for companies already operating in my sector.

At the interview stage I made a mistake: I was base only on the cost of living  rather than looking what the "job market" offers for the same work; I have indeed found out that for the same tasks (and maybe less overheads due to the introduction of a new business) some other companies operating in my sector and country offer (and state) minimum wages about 22% higher than mine. At that time  I was alone, but now I have a family and responsibilities are leading me to detect such differences.

I required recently a raise and I was demanded to show my progresses, performance and results which sounded satisfying to the management. Next steps will be negotiating about the entity of the raise.

My main wish would be compensating the gap and requesting at least +22% but I wonder whether they may argue that the resulting amount is too high for a simple raise if compared with the starting conditions; meanwhile, I would not be happy to know that such amount cannot be reached only because my starting wage was too low and then I need to wait long long time to get the amount company give now. Can the original agreement on the salary impact on the entity of the raise?

Comment: I do not know and I do not have the means to find it out unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but it seems like you're asking if you can ask for a 22% raise.

You can ask for whatever you want. They may give you the raise you ask for, or they may offer a lesser raise, or they may refuse to give you a raise altogether.

How you choose to proceed is up to you. If you don't get the raise you ask for you can take what they give you, or you can leave the company.

Comment: Do you think that they may leverage on a so high raise compared with the initial conditions to justify a reduced offer from their side?

Comment: Certainly they'll try to give you as small a raise as possible. It's up to you to accept or reject what they offer you.